# Как прочитать шаблон в zsh, как массив файлов

Tags: zsh

У меня есть такой скрипт на zsh. Он должен переименовывать расширения файлов по шаблону, например мы вводим терминале ren и затем набираем *.php -1 аргумент и *.txt - 2 аргумент, но после ввода в zsh str1 и str2 интерпретируются не как шаблоны, а как файлы с именами *.php и *.txt.

Мне нужно понять как сделать, чтобы было примерно так:

```
read test # вводим *.txt к примеру
echo $test # и должен выводиться список файлов, как в bash, но я не понимаю, как это сделать
```

Вот скрипт:

```
function ren {
    echo -n "Первый аргумент: "
    read str1 
    echo -n "Второй аргумент: "
    read str2
    for file in $arr1; do echo $file ; done
    #for file in $str1; do mv $file $(basename -- "$file" ${str1[@]:1})${str2[@]:1}; done

}
```

Я уже ничего не понимаю, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Так почему на баш не напишешь zsh совместим с баш помоему ну а если хочешь на zsh загляни в документацию с помощью команды find можно спокойно найти любой файл почитай как его использовать и загляни в документацию по zsh и будет тебе щастье

Comment: Все равно не понял